# How to inquire about the status of US Naturalization application?

Tags: usa, immigration

Last July I applied for naturalization in the US. At the time my application was received, I created an online account with the USCIS to track my case. When logged in, I see the status that USCIS received my application and a biometrics appointment was scheduled.

Since then, I already went to the biometrics appt. That was in August. But the status at the website never changed.

My wife went through the process last year, at the same office. She applied on August and by this time she already got her invitation for an interview and test.

Is there a way to inquire about the case status, other than physically getting to an appointment at their office?

Comment: Have you tried calling them?

Comment: So the website still says that a biometrics appointment is scheduled?

Comment: You can check the processing times of your local USCIS office [here](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do) (select your office under "Field Office", then on the next page look at the date for "N-400", compared to the date when they updated this information, for a sense of the timeframe). But 4 months seems well within the timeframe of most N-400 cases, so it doesn't seem unusual.

Comment: @user102008 +1 you should make it an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @Karlson - I don't think they provide a phone # for status inquiries. If you can point to one, please do.

Comment: @phoog - basically, yes.

Comment: @user102008 - Thanks. I remembered seeing this table in the past, but did not find it. Yes, it is within the time frame. Question is, is this the *total* time (from filing to oath) or just the mere "processing" time (from biometrics to interview)? Any idea? [BTW, Dorothy is right]

Comment: @ysap https://www.uscis.gov/about-us/contact-us you can check NCSC

Answer (score 2):

You can check the processing times of your local USCIS office [here](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do) (select your office under "Field Office", then on the next page look at the date for "N-400", compared to the date when they updated this information, for a sense of the timeframe). But 4 months seems well within the timeframe of most N-400 cases, so it doesn't seem unusual.